# Synchronous communication using NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C programming.

I have created two threads called add and display using the `NSInvocationOperation` and added it on to the `NSOperationQueue`.

I make the display thread to run first and then run the add thread. The display thread after printing the *"Welcome to display"* has to wait for the results to print from the add method.

So i have set the `waitUntilFinished` method.

Both the Operations are on the same queue. If i use `waitUntilFinished` for operations on the same queue there may be a situation for deadlock to happen(from apples developer documentation). Is it so?

To wait for particular time interval there is a method called `waitUntilDate:` 
But if i need to like this `wait(min(100,dmax));` let `dmax = 20;` How to do i wait for these conditions?

It would be much helpful if anyone can explain with an example.

EDITED:

```
threadss.h
------------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface threadss : NSObject {

    BOOL m_bRunThread;
    int a,b,c;
    NSOperationQueue* queue;
    NSInvocationOperation* operation;
    NSInvocationOperation* operation1;
    NSConditionLock* theConditionLock;

}
-(void)Thread;
-(void)add;
-(void)display;
@end

threadss.m
------------

#import "threadss.h"

@implementation threadss

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
     queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
     operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(display) object:nil];
     operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(add) object:nil];
     theConditionLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)Thread
{
    m_bRunThread = YES;

    //[operation addDependency:operation1];
    if (m_bRunThread) {
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    }
    //[operation addDependency:operation1];
    [queue addOperation:operation1];

    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(display) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    //NSLog(@"I'm going to do the asynchronous communication btwn the threads!!");
    //[self add];
    //[operation addDependency:self];
    sleep(1);
    [queue release];
    [operation release];
    //[operation1 release];
}
-(void)add
{
    NSLog(@"Going to add a and b!!");
    a=1;
    b=2;
    c = a + b;
    NSLog(@"Finished adding!!");
}
-(void)display
{
    NSLog(@"Into the display method");
    [operation1 waitUntilFinished];
    NSLog(@"The Result is:%d",c);

}
@end


main.m
-------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "threadss.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    threadss* thread = [[threadss alloc]init];
    [thread Thread];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

This is what i have tried with  a sample program.

### output

```
2011-06-03 19:40:47.898 threads_NSOperationQueue[3812:1503] Going to add a and b!!
2011-06-03 19:40:47.898 threads_NSOperationQueue[3812:1303] Into the display method
2011-06-03 19:40:47.902 threads_NSOperationQueue[3812:1503] Finished adding!!
2011-06-03 19:40:47.904 threads_NSOperationQueue[3812:1303] The Result is:3
```

Is the way of invoking the thread is correct.

1.Will there be any deadlock condition?

2.How to do wait(min(100,dmax)) where dmax = 50.

Comment: Please use question marks to denote questions.

Comment: @marcelo:Sorry will do from my next question onwards.

Comment: In Obj-C you should start all classes with a capital letter and all methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @kubi:Thanks.will change it like as you have said me to do.

Comment: Also, you aren't directly working with threads at all in this code, you're working with operations. The two operations may run on the same thread, they may run on different threads, but that level of detail is abstracted away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you have two operations:

1. Operation A: prints a message, waits for operation B to finish, continues
2. Operation B: prints a message

If this is the case, can you just print the first message, start operation B, then start operation A?

Also, when you are using `NSOperationQueue` you don't directly manage threads, it does all the thread management for you. So in your question when you said 'thread' you actually meant to say 'operation'.

---

To directly answer your question, "Can this cause a deadlock", yes it could. If you change the queue to be sequential instead of concurrent or if you make operation 2 dependent on operation 1 you will probably lock up. I'd recommend not trying to do what you're doing, refactor your code so that one operation doesn't need to pause while the other one works. Based on the code you've posted, there's no reason to structure your code like that.

Comment: How to implement this wait(min(100,dmax));

Comment: There's a good chance you don't want to do that. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying a sample code on threading(add and display).I have a cpp code to port to Objective C. There in the code waitForSingleObject is used to wait for an event as well as a timedelay. I need to wait for 100 milliseconds.Hope that can be made by using waitUntilDate:

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you, it is the iOS version of WaitForSingleObject in Windows:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[object runSomeLongOperation:^{
    // your own code here.
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
```